# Does the Wealthy Town ordinance raise Nook's home prices too?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

The Wealthy Town ordinance increases buy/sell prices at Re-Tail and the nooklings best I'm aware, so it's sort of a wash (unless you sell in a town with Wealth and buy in a town without). However do home expansions/public works projects also increase in price, or can Wealthy be used to get those quicker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wealthy Town ordinance appears to affect most prices in town.

The only exceptions are:

- **Turnip prices**, which are decided entirely by the game's RNG for Turnips.
- **Items sold in Re-Tail's sale slots**, which won't go higher in price than the one you set them in.
- **Home expansion loans**, which are set in stone for all players regardless of the ordinance.
- **Temporary services and goods**, such as Katrina's fortunes, opening an exhibit in the Museum, and drinking coffee at the Café.

While home expansion loans aren't affected, the cost of custom renovations such as doors, exteriors, and colours, will go up as a result of this ordinance.

E.g. A Mermaid Door that costs 4000 bells will instead cost 4800.

Comment: Public works projects are another exception and have their prices fixed like home expansion loans.